# Is SQLAlchemy/psycopg2 connection to PostgreSQL database encrypted

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

When I use SQLAlchemy with an external postgreSQL server, is the connection secured/encrypted?

`from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@ip:5432/mydatabase')`

What about psycopg2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your connection string does not indicate secure connection. However, sometimes connection might be secure nevertheless, but it is unlikely.

To have a secure connection to PostgreSQL database you can use `sslmode` parameter.

```
 engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@ip:5432/mydatabase?sslmode=verify-full')
```

`verify-full` is the highest level SSL connection validation where the client performs full SSL certificate check for the connection.

More info:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-ssl.html