# Connecting Python to Redshift through SSH and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-redshift

My current connection configuration is as follow, this is for redshift db

```
con=('postgresql://username:password@hostname:port/databasename')
    server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('ssh host', 22),
        ssh_username="-",
        ssh_password="-",
        remote_bind_address=('db host', port)
        )
    
    server.start()
    local_port = str(server.local_bind_port)
    engine = sa.create_engine(con)
    
    ######## Reaches here then times out when reading the table
    df_read = pd.read_sql_table('tablename',engine)
```

However, the Redshift database also has an SSH, which might be affecting the connection? It creates the engine but when reading the SQL in pd.read_sql_query I reach this error.

```
 (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
    Is the server running on host "xxx" (xxx) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port xxx?

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813312/is-sqlalchemy-psycopg2-connection-to-postgresql-database-encrypted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot SSH into a Redshift cluster but you can use SSL to secure the connection.

- [Amazon Redshift security overview](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_security-overview.html)
- [Configuring security options for connections](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-ssl-support.html)